# Dynamically update app.config file using WiX

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I have an msi built using WiX. Part of the installer collects some settings that will be entered into the app.config file of the installed app.

Now it works fine if I define `<util:XmlFile ...` for each setting that is going to change in the wxs file.

Now my question is this: is there a way I can dynamically create this util:XmlFile tag (e.g. from a custom action) so that I don't have to hard code it in to the wxs for each setting the app.config to update.

Answer (score 0):

How does it do the collection?  Are you doing an AppSearch and populating properties?  Can you just use the [PROPERTY] in your XmlFile element?  Note [PROP] is the value of PROP in MSI speak.

Comment: I looked into using that option however I could not see a way to use that option without hardcoding the property names I want to collect into my WSX file.

Essentially I have solved my issue by writing the settings I collect to a temporary xml file and this then allows me the most flexibility.